# Flatlist endReached firing itself without scrolling in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using Flatlist to display some data from an api but for some reason I can see the event is automatically triggered when the screen opens on load I can see all the request are being made at the same time without me scrolling the list!

Code:

```
    this.state = {
        isLoading: false,
        categories: [],
        page: 1,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCategories();
    }

    fetchCategories() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        categoryApi.getOne(this.state.page).then(response => {
            if (response.data) {
                this.setState({
                    categories: this.state.categories.concat(response.data.data),
                    isLoading: false,
                });
            } else {
                this.setState({isLoading: false});
                Alert.alert(
                    'Something wrong happened!',
                    'My Alert Msg',
                    [],
                    {cancelable: true}
                )
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    showMore = () => {
        // console.log("End reached.");
        this.setState({page: this.state.page + 1});
        this.fetchCategories();
    };





 <FlatList
                        data={this.state.categories}
                        extraData={this.state}
                        renderItem={(rowData) => <CategoryItem navigate={navigate} item={rowData}/>}
                        onEndReached={this.showMore}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                    />
```

Also seems that I have duplicate data on my flatlist for the first call, when page = 1.

Comment: Have you tried removing your `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: Couple thoughts: 1) inside `fetchCategories` how abt nest the request inside a check for `isLoading` 2) check the react-native issues page for instance [have you seen this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12827)? Might be a useful tweak in there!

Comment: Try setting `onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}`